# ExtJS 5: Using ExtJS SASS mixin in package

Tags: extjs, sass, compass-sass, extjs5, sencha-cmd

I know I'm doing something dumb, as I'm sure this is a simple fix. I followed the guides on setting up a package, and I was able to build and use my package just fine. Now I'm trying to add some styling to a TabPanel, so I figured add a UI... I add it in `sass/src/path/to/class`:

```
@include extjs-tab-panel-ui(
    $ui: 'wizard',
    $ui-tab-margin: 0
);
```

**sencha.cfg**

```
# The name of the package - should match the "name" property in ./package.json
#
package.name=MyPackage

# The namespace to which this package's SASS corresponds. The default value of
# "Ext" means that the files in ./sass/src (and ./sass/var) match classes in
# the Ext" root namespace. In other words, "Ext.panel.Panel" maps to
# ./sass/src/panel/Panel.scss.
#
# To style classes from any namespace, set this to blank. If this is blank,
# then to style "Ext.panel.Panel" you would put SASS in
# ./sass/src/Ext/panel/Panel.scss.
#
package.sass.namespace=MyPackage

# This is the comma-separated list of folders where classes reside. These
# classes must be explicitly required to be included in the build.
#
package.classpath=${package.dir}/src

# This is the comma-separated list of folders of overrides. All files in this
# path will be given a tag of "packageOverrides" which is automatically
# required in generated apps by the presence of this line in app.js:
#
#   //@require @packageOverrides
#
package.overrides=${package.dir}/overrides

# This is the folder where SASS "src" resides. This is searched for SCSS
# files that match the JavaScript classes used by the application.
#
package.sass.srcpath=${package.dir}/sass/src

package.theme=ext-theme-crisp

# This is the folder where SASS "vars" resides. This is searched for SCSS
# files that match the JavaScript classes used by the application.
#
package.sass.varpath=${package.dir}/sass/var

# This file is automatically imported into the SASS build before "vars".
#
package.sass.etcpath=${package.dir}/sass/etc/all.scss

# This is the folder in which to place "sencha packaage build" output.
#
package.build.dir=${package.dir}/build

# The folder that contains example application(s) for this package.
#
package.examples.dir=${package.dir}/examples

# The folder that contains sub-packages of this package. Only valid for "framework"
# package type.
#
package.subpkgs.dir=${package.dir}/packages

#==============================================================================
# Custom Properties - Place customizations below this line to avoid merge
# conflicts with newer versions

package.cmd.version=5.1.3.61
package.framework=ext
```

However, when I compile using **sencha package build**, I get an error saying **Undefined mixin 'extjs-tab-panel-ui'**. I tried doing several searches for this, but I couldn't turn up an answer that helped. I know I can create a custom theme package and use that, but I'd rather not. Is there anyway I can use the extjs-tab-panel-ui mixin? Am I missing an **@import**, and if so, what do I import?

Other things I've tried:

- Changing my package.sass.namespace to empty, and then splitting out
  the namespaces/adding the Ext namespace with my UI in
  sass/src/Ext/tab/Bar.scss
- Requiring Ext.tab.Panel in my class that's using the UI

Comment: Files don't import themselves, you need to find where whatever mixin you're trying to use is defined and then import that file.

Comment: @cimmanon, are you familiar with the Ext JS structure when it comes to styling?  I'm assuming I just have to look for where the mixin is defined, and import that file?  It's just strange that a package has to import, but an app created with Sencha Cmd does not have to import.  I'm assuming that's because an app is created differently/has the knowledge of where the themes live.

Comment: Basically, is there anyway to turn on `$include-ext-tab-panel` in the build?  It's currently set to false when I check `package/build/package-all-debug.scss`.  I think if I figured that out, this would work... if I use @import, I'm finding out it's leading me down a rabbit hole of importing everything.